# Find the selected radio input label from an unsorted-list of list-items Selenium C# Xpath

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, xpath, automation

A screenshot of that part of the page:

[image: read the value of selected item]

The HTML:

```html
<ul id="c2231_Fields_147_Value" name="Fields_147_Value" cvlid="Cushion">          
    <li>        
        <input type="radio" name="Fields_147_Value" value="" id="c2231_Fields_147_Value-0">        
        <label for="c2231_Fields_147_Value-0">(not set)</label>      
    </li>          
    <li>        
        <input type="radio" name="Fields_147_Value" value="Low" id="c2231_Fields_147_Value-1">        
        <label for="c2231_Fields_147_Value-1">Low</label>      
    </li>          
    <li>        
        <input type="radio" name="Fields_147_Value" value="Max" id="c2231_Fields_147_Value-2">        
        <label for="c2231_Fields_147_Value-2">Max</label>      
    </li>          
    <li>        
        <input type="radio" name="Fields_147_Value" value="Moderate" id="c2231_Fields_147_Value-3">        
        <label for="c2231_Fields_147_Value-3">Moderate</label>      
    </li>      
</ul>
```

in the above elements, one radio is selected,
And I want the label text corresponding to the selected radio input.

For example, if the radio of 'Max' , is selected , then I want to read the value 'Max'

There are 4 input radio and 4 corresponding labels under unsorted list.
Each list item is a set of one input of type radio and one label.

User can select only one input since it is radio type.

How to read the value of selected input using C# and xpath ?

I  have written following code and xapths but only the 1st xpath returned values , and it does not support list of list of Iwebelement, I guess, therefor my logic of IsSelected is always coming as true.

But when i tried with xpath for collection of input and collection of label separately, both worked at inspection time,
but while running the code in visual studio ,both returned empty list.

============my code=========and xpaths=========

```cs
public IList<IWebElement> CushionItemsList { get { return driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//ul[@cvlid='Cushion']/li")); } }
public IList<IWebElement> CushionItemsListInputs { get { return driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//ul[@cvlid='Cushion']/li/input")); } }
public IList<IWebElement> CushionItemsListLabels { get { return driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//ul[@cvlid='Cushion']/li/label")); } }

public string GetSelectedCushionValue()
{
    string cushionValue = string.Empty;
    int x = CushionItemsListInputs.Count();

    for (int i = 0; i < CushionItemsListInputs.Count(); i++)
    {
        bool selected = CushionItemsListInputs[i].Selected;
        if (selected == true)
        {
            cushionValue = CushionItemsListLabels[i].Text;
        }
    }

    return cushionValue;
}
```

===============================================

[image: read value of selected item]

Comment: edit your question instead adding comments

Comment: Do you see `selected` attribute during run time in any of the tags?